# Magento 2 Terms and Conditions

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

am having a problem on checkout it gives me error message

> "Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the
>   order"

but the whole block not showing and it's enabled and i've put a condition!

Comment: you want to add a multiple terms and condition and all are require field right.

Comment: I just want to add one condition, but the block not showing at all @HIrenKadivar

Comment: where to put a condition in block?

Comment: Checkout at last step (Payment)

Comment: please update your question in details. so i can help you. with files and code

Comment: you want to add Terms and Conditions on checkout page after payment method.

Comment: Yes, I want it after payment @HIrenKadivar

Comment: check it here  https://prnt.sc/mjj52h

Comment: Yeah exactly that's what i want

Comment: please i update answer my check it its working fine then accpet and upvote please thanks

Comment: The problem is I've already did these two steps that's why am wondering why it's not showing!

Comment: please clear cache from admin > system > Cache Management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add terms and conditions to checkout page**

> step:1

you will have to log in your admin account then follow this path **Store > Terms and Conditions**.

[image]

> step:2

After saving new terms and conditions, go to **Store > Configuration**.

Choose **Sales > Checkout**. Expand the **Checkout Options** section, set the **Enable Terms and Conditions** field to Yes and click on Save Config button.

[image]

Comment: @Dalia Abu Ghoush please check it its wokring accpet and upvote please.

Comment: It is enabled in both but still not showing, any thoughts?
I have done setup:upgrade setup:di:compile setup:static-content:deploy and cache clear and indexer:reindex

far out.